# ideal Operating System for Scala Application Stack: Fedora or CentOS

Tags: scala, playframework, centos, fedora

I am thinking about opening up a VPS account for deploying a Scala application (most likely using the Playframework, but open to the possibility of Scalatra).  I may also want to do some Python scripting on this VPS as well.

I'm assuming performance, stability and security-wise either choice would do fine but my real question is: which OS would be *easier* to get up and going with Scala and Play?  I'd very much prefer to set everything up rather quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were up to me, I'd go with CentOS. I have found them both about the same to get setup, but CentOS will save you a lot of headaches after a few years as Fedora reaches it's end of life and YUM repos disappear. You don't get the absolute latest versions with CentOS, but you can usually work around that if necessary by adding a new Repo.

I've had experience with both, running Java and Scala webapps. We've pretty much moved away from Fedora for that purpose for the reason above.

Comment: That's a pretty compelling reason to go with CentOS, then.  I was originally leaning towards CentOS, but this confirms it for me then.  Thanks!